# Grouping by day then count result for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I'm having trouble getting my head around this. I'm using MS SQL 2008 and I have a table for example called Activity, with 3 fields: customer (a customer's identity), visitDate (a the date that they visited) and customerType (what type of cutomer they are). Here's 3 days' of data:

```
customer    visitDate                   customerType

customer1   2013-10-01 07:00:00.000     A
customer1   2013-10-01 09:00:00.000     A
customer2   2013-10-01 10:00:00.000     B

customer1   2013-10-02 09:00:00.000     A
customer2   2013-10-02 09:00:00.000     B
customer3   2013-10-02 09:00:00.000     B
customer1   2013-10-02 09:00:00.000     A

customer1   2013-10-03 07:00:00.000     A
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to write a query that groups the data showing each day which also counts the user types for each day so that the result looks like this:

```
visitDate   TypeA   TypeB   Total

2013-10-01  1       1       2
2013-10-02  1       2       3
2013-10-03  1       0       0
```

Note that if someone visits more than once on the same day they are only counted as one visit that day.

I know it's got something to do with grouping but I haven't got a clue where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slightly tricky bit is to only count a customer once for a given day and type, even if they have multiple records for that day:

```
select 
   visitDate, 
   sum(case when customerType = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as TypeA,
   sum(case when customerType = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as TypeB,
   count(*) as Total
from (
    select distinct 
        customer, 
        cast(visitdate as date) as visitdate, 
        customertype from activity
    ) x
group by 
    visitdate
```

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16535/2)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

```
select visitDate, 
       sum(case when customerType = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as TypeA,
       sum(case when customerType = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as TypeB,
       count(*) as Total
from activity
group by visitDate
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also cut the time part of the `DateTime` field:

```
select 
  cast(visitDate as Date) as visitDate, 
  sum(case customerType when 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as TypeA,
  sum(case customerType when 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as TypeB,
  count(*) as Total
from activity
group by cast(visitDate as Date)
```